# AWS ECR repository

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecr

I have a requirement to group my ECR images based on a department. Currently we are in one single AWS account and we plan to have deployments to different regions within this AWS account. I have a repository in ECR which resembles this `512234521735.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/finance` where `finance` (department) is the repository name.

All members within the finance team would want to push their specific images to this repository. Some examples of the images -

```
512234521735.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/finance/banking/adam:latest
512234521735.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/finance/investment/bella:latest
512234521735.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/finance/budget/morgan:latest
512234521735.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/finance/savings/chelsea:latest
```

Currently I am not able to push to the `finance` repository as it errors out saying there is no repository by name `512234521735.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/finance/banking/adam` Is there a way to work around this without actually creating the repos for each team member and just use the `finance` repo? AWS talks about the namespace pattern which does not make a lot of sense.

Any work around/help is much appreciated.

Comment: how about using the employee name as tags :) but you can only have one 512234521735.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/finance/my-image:adam

Comment: it is not the same image for all employees. so using them as tags wouldn't work.

Comment: A repository = Single Docker Image, you will need to create separate repositories